# Turn off tail call optimization for debugging in Chez Scheme

Tags: debugging, scheme, chez-scheme

I am debugging the following program in Chez Scheme.

```lisp
(define (proc3 x3)
  (printf "proc3 ~a\n" (+ 1 x3)))

(define (proc2 x2)
  (printf "proc2 ~a\n" x2)
  (proc3 x2))

(define (proc1 x1)
  (printf "proc1 ~a\n" x1)
  (proc2 x1))

(proc1 'a)
```

Run this program will raise a error.

`(debug)` this program results the following information:

```
$ scheme
Chez Scheme Version 9.5
Copyright 1984-2017 Cisco Systems, Inc.

> (load "debugging.scm")
proc1 a
proc2 a
Exception in +: a is not a number
Type (debug) to enter the debugger.
> (debug)
debug> i
#<continuation in proc3>                                          : sf
  0: #<continuation in proc3>
  1: #<system continuation in ksrc>
  2: #<system continuation>
  3: #<system continuation in dynamic-wind>
  4: #<system continuation in dynamic-wind>
  5: #<system continuation in $reset-protect>
  6: #<system continuation in new-cafe>
#<continuation in proc3>                                          :
```

Notice that the stack frames only contains the last frame `proc3`, but I'd like to show `proc2` and `proc1`. This seems to be due to Scheme's TCO (tail call optimization) prevents the debugger from inspecting the precise call stack frames.

If I put the call `(proc3 x2)` and `(proc2 x1)` not at the tail position, the debugger can print the precise call stack frames normally.

```lisp
(define (proc3 x3)
  (printf "proc3 ~a\n" (+ 1 x3)))

(define (proc2 x2)
  (printf "proc2 ~a\n" x2)
  (proc3 x2)
  (printf "proc2 leave\n"))

(define (proc1 x1)
  (printf "proc1 ~a\n" x1)
  (proc2 x1)
  (printf "proc1 leave\n"))

(proc1 'a)
```

```
$ scheme
Chez Scheme Version 9.5
Copyright 1984-2017 Cisco Systems, Inc.

> (load "debugging.scm")
proc1 a
proc2 a
Exception in +: a is not a number
Type (debug) to enter the debugger.
> (debug)
debug> i
#<continuation in proc3>                                          : sf
  0: #<continuation in proc3>
  1: #<continuation in proc2>
  2: #<continuation in proc1>
  3: #<system continuation in ksrc>
  4: #<system continuation>
  5: #<system continuation in dynamic-wind>
  6: #<system continuation in dynamic-wind>
  7: #<system continuation in $reset-protect>
  8: #<system continuation in new-cafe>
#<continuation in proc3>                                          :
```

Is there way to turn off the TCO temporarily in Chez Scheme? (Just for debugging)

Thanks.

Comment: If this were possible, I expect it would be of quite limited utility. A lot of Scheme programs depend on cheap tail calls to work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for sure not possible, as scheme specification imposes tail recursive calls to become iterative processes.

In the implementation, there is an `APPLY return code` that drops the stack frames of the iterative processes made via tail recursion -- the interpreter does `SCODE` check for `"NULL == CDR(SCODE)"` as a special condition for returning code of type `APPLY`.

If you want to happen as you with, you can modify this condition in the eval and recompile the scheme -- which will not be scheme any more.

If you want to debug, other methods can be applied.